# python throwing an error HTTP 401 while accessing https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json

Tags: python, pycurl

This is the Code I am running to get the stream of tweets using Streaming API by accessing the stream.twitter url mentioned in title. but it is throwing an error (HTTP error 401)
In the code I am trying to track multiple terms

```
import time
import pycurl
import urllib
import json
import oauth2 
API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json'
USER_AGENT = 'TwitterStream 1.0'
OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key': 'ABC',
              'consumer_secret': 'ABC',
              'access_token_key': 'ABC',
              'access_token_secret': 'ABC'}
POST_PARAMS = {'include_entities': 0,
               'stall_warning': 'true',
               'track': 'iphone,ipad,ipod'}
class TwitterStream():
    def __init__(self, timeout=False):
        #self.oauth_token = Token(key=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_secret'])
        self.oauth_consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
        self.oauth_token = oauth2.Token(key=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_secret'])
        self.conn = None #pycurl.Curl()
        self.buffer = ''
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.setup_connection()

    def setup_connection(self):
        """ Create persistant HTTP connection to Streaming API endpoint using cURL.
        """
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
            self.buffer = ''
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
        # Restart connection if less than 1 byte/s is received during "timeout" seconds
        if isinstance(self.timeout, int):
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1)
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.LOW_SPEED_TIME, self.timeout)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, API_ENDPOINT_URL)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, USER_AGENT)
        # Using gzip is optional but saves us bandwidth.
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, 'deflate, gzip')
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, urllib.urlencode(POST_PARAMS))
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Host: stream.twitter.com',
                                             'Authorization: %s' % self.get_oauth_header()])
        # self.handle_tweet is the method that are called when new tweets arrive
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.handle_tweet)

    def get_oauth_header(self):
        """ Create and return OAuth header.
        """
        params = {'oauth2_version': '1.0',
                  'oauth2_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
                  'oauth2_timestamp': int(time.time())}
        req = oauth2.Request(method='POST', parameters=params, url='%s?%s' % (API_ENDPOINT_URL,
                                                                             urllib.urlencode(POST_PARAMS)))
        req.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), self.oauth_consumer, self.oauth_token)
        return req.to_header()['Authorization'].encode('utf-8')

    def start(self):
        """ Start listening to Streaming endpoint.
        Handle exceptions according to Twitter's recommendations.
        """
        backoff_network_error = 0.25
        backoff_http_error = 5
        backoff_rate_limit = 60
        while True:
            self.setup_connection()
            try:
                self.conn.perform()
            except:
                # Network error, use linear back off up to 16 seconds
                print 'Network error: %s' % self.conn.errstr()
                print 'Waiting %s seconds before trying again' % backoff_network_error
                time.sleep(backoff_network_error)
                backoff_network_error = min(backoff_network_error + 1, 16)
                continue
            # HTTP Error
            sc = self.conn.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
            if sc == 420:
                # Rate limit, use exponential back off starting with 1 minute and double each attempt
                print 'Rate limit, waiting %s seconds' % backoff_rate_limit
                time.sleep(backoff_rate_limit)
                backoff_rate_limit *= 2
            else:
                # HTTP error, use exponential back off up to 320 seconds
                print 'HTTP error %s, %s' % (sc, self.conn.errstr())
                print 'Waiting %s seconds' % backoff_http_error
                time.sleep(backoff_http_error)
                backoff_http_error = min(backoff_http_error * 2, 320)

    def handle_tweet(self, data):
        """ This method is called when data is received through Streaming endpoint.
        """
        self.buffer += data
        if data.endswith('\r\n') and self.buffer.strip():
            # complete message received
            message = json.loads(self.buffer)
            self.buffer = ''
            msg = ''
            if message.get('limit'):
                print 'Rate limiting caused us to miss %s tweets' % (message['limit'].get('track'))
            elif message.get('disconnect'):
                raise Exception('Got disconnect: %s' % message['disconnect'].get('reason'))
            elif message.get('warning'):
                print 'Got warning: %s' % message['warning'].get('message')
            else:
                print 'Got tweet with text: %s' % message.get('text')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ts = TwitterStream()
    ts.setup_connection()
    ts.start()
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Is `OAUTH_KEYS` supposed to be full of what looks like meaningless garbage? The error says you're unauthorized, which would be exactly what you'd expect if you handed the server nonsense and said it was authorization.

Comment: Are you talking about the credentials I use in this code as 'ABC'?

Comment: Yes. Those don't look like valid keys.

Comment: I have used my own credentials in the running code. I did not show them up here as for security purpose. I have used valid keys & Auth tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating your clock.

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

From: http://lembra.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/twitter-stream-mysterious-401unauthorized-status-with-oauth-and-clock-issue/